# Drupal 7 content organization with panels, taxonomy, nodes and pathauto

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy, pathauto, drupal-nodes

i wanted to know what is the most possible way to organize content in drupal 7, using pathauto and taxonomy to get links like:

category/subcategory/node

where category and subcategory also can be treated like a node (if you go to example.com/category or example.com/category/subcategory it will display an article)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the path like below for node links :

```
[node:taxonomy-{yourvocabularyname}:parents:join-path]/[node:taxonomy-{yourvocabularyname}:name]/[node:title]
```

It will give you category/subcategory/nodetitle.

But i didn't understood the second part of your request...